# Как убрать админку на сторонний app (Django admin)

Tags: python, django

Скорее всего вопрос легкий, просто не знаю, как прогуглить. Есть пакеты, которые лежат в site-packages питона или же самой [Django](https://www.djangoproject.com/). Например, [auth](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/). И я хочу их убрать из админки или settings подредактировать. Выходит, что я должен к себе в проект для этого устанавливать app?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Хотите убрать из админки модели User и Group? Тогда вот так в любом вашем admin.py:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User, Group
admin.site.unregister(User)
admin.site.unregister(Group)
```

Вот только нужно будет и из сеттингов повыпиливать все вызовы, иначе ошибки будут. Поэкспериментируйте - должно помочь. Лично у меня джанга ругается на отсутствие этих моделей в админке :)

Comment: а у меня без ошибок , спасибо =)

Comment: Не за что :) Пометьте ответ, как принятый.

Comment: еще ни разу не принимал ответы...все обшарил, где принять ? =))))

Comment: Здесь, возле ответа на Ваш вопрос - под голосованием за/против - иконка галочки в кружочке.

Comment: оооопа, даже не обратил на нее внимание =)

Answer (score 1):

Устанавливать вы можете какие угодно дополнения, но какие из них подключить это уже ваше дело. Подключать в *settings* в **INSTALLED_APPS**, те пакеты которые не хотите чтобы подключались, просто уберите их из **INSTALLED_APPS**, однако не забудьте удалить вызовы из других *views*, иначе ошибка будет.

Comment: наверно вы вопрос не правильно поняли. Вот у меня установлено в setting.py django.contrib.auth, а как сделать чтобы в админку это не добавлялось?

Comment: Нда, не совсем понял, но частично мой ответ тоже был правильным, только конечно без самого ключевого момента ) Правильно-ответчику +1